# Update method not updating table using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having difficulty translating the Headfirst into Rails book which is based on Rails 2 into Rails 4 which is set up on my machine.
The exercise is trying to retrieve a record from a database and then, once edited, update the table.
I have tried many different ways and my current configuration is as follows - this will present the record for editing but will not actually update the record! (Infuriating!)
NB - I am not using 'strong_parameters' nor 'protected_attributes' - I did try this but was getting stack to deep and other errors.
My ad model is also empty - I have removed the att_accessible entries that I tried with the protected attributes gem.

Here is my - ad controller entry:

```
def update
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    @ad.update_attributes(update_params[:id])
    redirect_to "/ads/#{@ad.id}"
end

 private
def update_params
    params.permit(:name, :description, :price, :seller_id, :email, :ad, :img_url)
end

end
```

EDIT VIEW:

```
<h1>Editing <%= @ad.name %></h1>
<%= form_for(@ad,:url=>{:action=>'update'}) do |f| %>
<p><b>Name</b><br /><%= f.text_field :name %></p>
<p><b>Description</b><br /><%= f.text_area :description %></p>
<p><b>Price</b><br /><%= f.text_field :price %></p>
<p><b>Seller</b><br /><%= f.text_field :seller_id %></p>
<p><b>Email</b><br /><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
<p><b>Img Url</b><br /><%= f.text_field :img_url %></p>
<p><%= f.submit "update" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Log Entry on Update:

```
   Started PATCH "/ads/1/update" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-13 22:35:51 +0100
    Processing by AdsController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"O4cN72FXCCkfkL7M6bozodbB0Aqor
    NctOOV5sfXdado=", "ad"=>{"name"=>"Typewriter", "description"=>"Old manual typewr
    iter. Many years useful service. Works best with a bottle next to it.", "price"=

>"71.95", "seller_id"=>"54", "email"=>"dhammett@email.com1", "img_url"=>"http://
homepage.mac.com/david_griffiths/typewriter.png"}, "commit"=>"update", "id"=>"1"
}
  ←[1m←[35mAd Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads" WHERE "ads"."id" = ? L
IMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, ad, commit, id
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mbegin transaction←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/ads/1
Completed 302 Found in 54ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: Look at this line; You're calling `update_params` incorrectly: `@ad.update_attributes(update_params[:id])`

Comment: Please can you help me here - what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I have updated my update as follows                                        `def update
 @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
 @ad.update_attributes!(params[:ad].permit(:name, :description, :price, :seller_id, :email, :ad, :img_url, :id))
 redirect_to "/ads/#{@ad.id}"`

Comment: This update has worked and will allow me to update the fields and removes the need for the update_params